# Bash: Mask a filename with another name, inline?

Tags: bash, filenames

The problem here is as follows: I have a python project with python and bash cli tools.  I have structured the executables' CLI interfaces in compliance, more or less, with POSIX interface standards.

I deposit them into a root bin folder without their extensions.  I leverage these tools in scripts and modular compositions,

```
this-tool ... | that-tool ...
```

And it is really helpful for readability and maintainability when these tools do not have any random extensions attached to them.

Consider the example of a Bash script hastily written that is migrated to a more comprehensive python script: why should this move break the pipelines that leverage the tool's name and interface?

---

Anyhow, in this vein, I have run into a problem.  A particular 3rd party tool performs an extension check on executable files: it checks to make sure that the file it is running is a python file with a `.py` extension.

```
$ other-guys-thing run mytool ...
ERROR! 
   The file needs to be a python file with a .py extension!!!
```

My issue is that I can either create a symbolic link or copy the executable to a local context with a `.py` extension. Or I could do this fancy other thing, and mask the filename with something else using Bash semantics.

Is that possible?

Comment: Creating a link, hard or symbolic, could be an option that I could go along with if patching the 3rd-party tool was out of the question. Is your reason for not wanting to do that purely aesthetic? There is nothing `bash`-related that would influence a string comparison in an unknown application.

Comment: Does the 3rd party tool do `python3 mytool`?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I am pretty sure it has already called python internally, and is consuming the python file inside some kind of a loop (it is `streamlit`)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `it has already called python internally`. Is the app itself written in Python? Are you sure it actually *can* run non-python scripts?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk it absolutely cannot run non python scripts.  Basically, the issue is that, when it is in a container, the script that it is accessing is in the bin folder, and I have removed the `.py` from the script so that the tools are bald.  It doesn't like that, and I am trying to work around it.

Comment: The tool is broken. I guess the best option is a symlink, so at least when your real code gets updated the compatibility file is "updated" too